# Changing the language in a beamer presentation with mtheme

Tags: beamer, fontspec, languages

I want to set the main language of my beamer presentation to German, in order to have German dates for `\today` etc. I use the `mtheme` by Matthias Vogelgesang. A minimal example (from the demo file) would look like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{m}
\renewcommand{\mthemetitleformat}{\scshape\MakeLowercase}

\usepackage{booktabs}


\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Fira Sans}
\setmonofont{Fira Mono}

\title{A modern beamer theme}
\subtitle{}
\date{\today}
\author{Matthias Vogelgesang}
\institute{Institute or miscellaneous information}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Table of Contents}
  \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
  \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{mtheme}

  The \emph{mtheme} is a Beamer theme with minimal visual noise inspired by the
  \href{https://github.com/hsrmbeamertheme/hsrmbeamertheme}{\textsc{hsrm} Beamer
  Theme} by Benjamin Weiss.

  Enable the theme by loading

  \begin{verbatim}    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usetheme{m}\end{verbatim}

  Note, that you have to have Mozilla's \emph{Fira Sans} font and XeTeX
  installed to enjoy this wonderful typography.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However, this doesn't compile. The error I get is

```
! Undefined control sequence.<argument> \c_keys_code_root_tlfontspec/Ligatures/Historical ...tureoption{Ligatures}{Historic}{Historical}
```

on line 8 as well as

```
! Undefined control sequence.\fontspec_get_features:n ...st ,#1}\str_if_eq:xxF{\l_fontspec_hexcol_tl \l_... ... BoldFont={Fira Sans}]{Fira Sans Light}
```

on line 26 as well as a whole bunch of others. I installed the whole Fira Sans Package as well as Fira Mono, so right now I'm confused, because the pure demo works just fine...The documentation for mtheme didn't have a section on changing languages too.

My system runs on MiKTeX 2.9 with an updated database and TeXMaker as editing software.

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please respect the format of the error messages? My impression is that you don't have the latest version of the `l3` packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all please consider getting in touch through [GitHub](https://github.com/matze/mtheme) in the future in case you have any problems with the theme. Right now it is under heavy development so if you have problems we would like to hear about it. On Stackexchange it is likely that we miss it.

As suggested by @egreg please update *all* your packages first. I can't really help you with that as I don't use MiKTeX, but updating should be straight forward – as described for examples [here](http://miktex.org/howto/update-miktex).

Based on your 'MWE' I made a real one where I removed all the unnecessary stuff and added the `babel` package for the german language support. Most important: You don't need to nor should you load `fontspec` on your own. This is done by mtheme itself if it is necessary.

So please try to run the following and report back.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usetheme{m}

\title{Meine mtheme Präsentation}
\subtitle{}
\date{\today}
\author{PMPJohn}
\institute{Mein Institut}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Einleitung}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Meine Folienüberschrift}
  Meine erste Folie!
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Not requiring `fontspec` was one thing, but I think I forgot to also update the packages with user rights as well instead of Admin only. Unfortunately I can only accept the answer and not upvote you due to low rep...